# ¿Como convertir la data de ajax (DataTable) en un ciclo for?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Normalmente uso ajax y en el `.done` hago un ciclo for para que los datos que recibio los muestre en la vista de la sgte manera:

```
for (var i = data.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var rowNode = table
                .row.add([  
                            data[i].nombre,
                            data[i].apellido,

                        ])
                    .draw()
               .node();
            }
```

Lo que sucede ahora es que no deseo usar ajax sino netamente la funcion de datatables pero no sabria como realizar un ciclo for dentro de esa funcion para cargar los datos en la data...

**CODIGO DATATABLES**

```
$(function() {
    var table = $('.row-details-data-table').DataTable({
        "ajax": "../students",
        dom: '<"tbl-top clearfix"lfr>,t,<"tbl-footer clearfix"<"tbl-info pull-left"i><"tbl-pagin pull-right"p>>',
        "columns": [{
            "class": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        }, {
            "data": "name"
        }, {
            "data": "position"
        }, {
            "data": "office"
        }, {
            "data": "salary"
        }],
        "order": [
            [1, 'asc']
        ]
});
```

Les Agradeceria un monton..

Comment: ¿Mi respuesta te ha servido para solucionar tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías resolverlo de 2 formas:

- Formatear la respuesta del `endpoint` al formato esperado por defecto:

  ```
  {
    "draw": 1, // este dato se envía y se espera que sea devuelto como parte de las respuesta
    "recordsTotal": 57, // (Opcional) Registros en filtrados (eg "data.length")
    "recordsFiltered": 57, // (Opcional) Total de registros (si la respuesta está paginada)
    "data": [{...}] // Arreglo con los registros
  }
  ```

  [Ver ejemplo](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)
- Otra opción es usar [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc)

> [...] `dataSrc` proporcionar la capacidad de alterar qué datos leerá el `DataTables` desde el retorno `JSON` desde el servidor[...]

Ejemplo:

```
var table = $('.row-details-data-table').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '../students',
    dataSrc: function(data) {
       return {
         data: data
       };
    }
  },
  dom: '<"tbl-top clearfix"lfr>,t,<"tbl-footer clearfix"<"tbl-info pull-left"i><"tbl-pagin pull-right"p>>',
  columns: [{
    "class": 'details-control',
    "orderable": false,
    "data": null,
    "defaultContent": ''
  }, {
    "data": "name"
  }, {
    "data": "position"
  }, {
    "data": "office"
  }, {
    "data": "salary"
  }],
  order: [
    [1, 'asc']
  ]
});
```